# How to run TexShop scripts from the terminal on OSX

Tags: texshop, scripts

I wish to run the following scripts/commands from the command line:

pdflatexmk,
the command that cleans the directory, i.e. only keeps the .tex, .pdf, .bib files.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you very much
Menghan